# redirect wrong urls or domains to specified page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect the below URL :

```
http://ABC.mywebsite.com/
```

To this URL :

```
http://mywebsite.com/error.html
```

So I had tried the options listed below, But custom errors tag is not working  :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.html">

</customErrors>
```

And also this not working :

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.html">

        <error statusCode="204" redirect="Default.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="400" redirect="Default.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="Default.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Default.aspx" />

    </customErrors>
```

And also below code is not working :

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


       Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

        if (exc is HttpUnhandledException)
        {
            // Pass the error on to the error page.
            Server.Transfer("Error.html");
        }   

    }
```

How can fix my problem , I think the problem is not in the application context , maybe it is in IIS context , thanks in adance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the IIS URL Rewriting module could be the way to go.

You would need to install it on the IIS server: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

There are nice tutorials here:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module

You can then try using configuration similar to the following (adding this to your web.config):

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to error" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^ABC\.mywebsite\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://mywebsite.com/error.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope that helps you.